# Does fmodf() cause a hardfault in stm32?

Tags: c, stm32, nucleo, fmodf

I am trying to create a modulated waveform out of 2 sine waves.
To do this I need the modulo(fmodf) to know what amplitude a sine with a specific frequency(lo_frequency) has at that time(t). But I get a hardfault when the following line is executed:

```
j = fmodf(2 * PI * lo_frequency * t, 2 * PI);
```

Do you have an idea why this gives me a hardfault ?

#### Edit 1:

I exchanged fmodf with my_fmodf:

```
float my_fmodf(float x, float y){
    if(y == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    float n = x / y;
    return x - n * y;
}
```

But still the hardfault occurs, and when I debug it it doesn't even jump into this function(my_fmodf).

Heres the whole function in which this error occurs:

```
int* create_wave(int* message){
    /* Mixes the message signal at 10kHz and the carrier at 40kHz.
     * When a bit of the message is 0 the amplitude is lowered to 10%.
     * When a bit of the message is 1 the amplitude is 100%.
     * The output of the STM32 can't be negative, thats why the wave swings between
     * 0 and 256 (8bit precision for faster DAC)
     */
    static int rf_frequency = 10000;
    static int lo_frequency = 40000;
    static int sample_rate = 100000;
    int output[sample_rate];
    int index, mix;
    float j, t;
    for(int i = 0; i <= sample_rate; i++){
        t = i * 0.00000001f; // i * 10^-8
        j = my_fmodf(2 * PI * lo_frequency * t, 2 * PI);

        if (j < 0){
            j += (float) 2 * PI;
        }
        index = floor((16.0f / (lo_frequency/rf_frequency * 0.0001f)) * t);
        if (index < 16) {
            if (!message[index]) {
                mix = 115 + sin1(j) * 0.1f;
            } else {
                mix = sin1(j);
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
        output[i] = mix;
    }
    return output;
}
```

#### Edit 2:

I fixed the warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr] the way "chux - Reinstate Monica" suggested.

```
int* create_wave(int* message){
    static uint16_t rf_frequency = 10000;
    static uint32_t lo_frequency = 40000;
    static uint32_t sample_rate = 100000;
    int *output = malloc(sizeof *output * sample_rate);
    uint8_t index, mix;
    float j, n, t;
    for(int i = 0; i < sample_rate; i++){
        t = i * 0.00000001f; // i * 10^-8
        j = fmodf(2 * PI * lo_frequency * t, 2 * PI);
        if (j < 0){
            j += 2 * PI;
        }
        index = floor((16.0f / (lo_frequency/rf_frequency * 0.0001f)) * t);
        if (index < 16) {
            if (!message[index]) {
                mix = (uint8_t) floor(115 + sin1(j) * 0.1f);
            } else {
                mix = sin1(j);
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
        output[i] = mix;
    }
    return output;
}
```

But now I get the hardfault on this line:

```
output[i] = mix;
```

#### EDIT 3:

Because the previous code contained a very large buffer array that did not fit into the 16KB SRAM of the STM32F303K8 I needed to change it.

Now I use a "ping-pong" buffer where I use the callback of the DMA for "first-half-transmitted" and "completly-transmitted":

```
void HAL_DAC_ConvHalfCpltCallbackCh1(DAC_HandleTypeDef * hdac){
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < 128; i++){
        new_value = sin_table[(i * 8) % 256];
        if (message[message_index] == 0x0){
            dac_buf[i] = new_value * 0.1f + 115;
        } else {
            dac_buf[i] = new_value;
        }
    }
}

void HAL_DAC_ConvCpltCallbackCh1 (DAC_HandleTypeDef * hdac){
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    for(uint16_t i = 128; i < 256; i++){
        new_value = sin_table[(i * 8) % 256];
        if (message[message_index] == 0x0){
            dac_buf[i] = new_value * 0.1f + 115;
        } else {
            dac_buf[i] = new_value;
        }
    }
    message_index++;
    if (message_index >= 16) {
        message_index = 0;
        // HAL_DAC_Stop_DMA (&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_1);
    }
}
```

And it works the way I wanted:
[image: output]

But the frequency of the created sine is too low.
I cap at around 20kHz but I'd need 40kHz.
I allready increased the clock by a factor of 8 so that one is maxed out:
[image: maxed].
I can still decrease the counter period (it is 50 at the moment), but when I do so the interrupt callback seems to take longer than the period to the next one.
At least it seems so as the output becomes very distorted when I do that.

I also tried to decrease the precision by taking only every 8th sine value but
I cant do this any more because then the output does not look like a sine wave anymore.

Any ideas how I could optimize the callback so that it takes less time ?
Any other ideas ?

Comment: Can you post the assembly emitted for `my_fmodf`?

Comment: `in stm32` Which stm32 exactly? `return output;` is invalid. What compiler are you using? For starters, enable all compiler warnings `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and fix them all.

Comment: The STM32F303K8. I'm using MinGW. I am debuging with the STM Cube IDE.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that "return output" is invalid I still need to wrap my head around how to return arrays and such in C coming from Java&Python.

Comment: @le_lemon A C function cannot return an _array_.  It can return a pointer to allocated memory.  It can return an array in a `struct`.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof *output * sample_rate);` Check the return value of `malloc` for errors. Does you stm32 has _at least_ 100000 * 4 = 390kilobytes of memory? Which stm32 are you using? How are you compiling it? What is  the input to the function? What linking options are you using? `hardfault on this line:output[i] = mix;` because most probably you do not have enough memory and `output` is NULL.

Comment: Oof ... it only has 16KB SRAM (https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f303k8.pdf)

Comment: output after malloc is 0x20003000 that is not NULL right ?

Comment: I just reduced the sample_rate to 10 just to see if the error still occurs and it still does.

Comment: Failures could be due to missing `#include <math.h>`.  Curious code is using `floor()` vs. `floorf()`.  Consider a [mcve] so others can re-create the issue for a speedier solution.

Comment: @le_lemon even if this time it "works" you should working with the uCs, avoid malloc and family functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does fmodf() cause a hardfault in stm32?

It is other code problems causing the hard fault here.

**Failing to compile with ample warnings**

Best code tip: enable all warnings. [@KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371032/does-fmodf-cause-a-hardfault-in-stm32/64371428#comment113826946_64371032)
Faster feedback than Stackoverflow.

I'd expect something like below on a well enabled compiler.

```
return output;
warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

**Returning a local Object**

Cannot return a local array.  Allocate instead.

```
// int output[sample_rate];
int *output = malloc(sizeof *output * sample_rate);
return output;
```

Calling code will need to `free()` the pointer.

**Out of range array access**

```
static int sample_rate = 100000;
int output[sample_rate];

// for(int i = 0; i <= sample_rate; i++){
for(int i = 0; i < sample_rate; i++){
    ...
    output[i] = mix;
}
```

**Stack overflow?**

`static int sample_rate = 100000;  int output[sample_rate];` is a large local variable.  Maybe allocate or try something smaller?

**Advanced: loss of precision**

A good `fmodf()` does not lose precision.  For a more precise answer consider `double` math for the intermediate results.  An even better approach is more involved.

```
float my_fmodf(float x, float y){
    if(y == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    double n = 1.0 * x / y;
    return (float) (x - n * y);
}
```

> Can I not use any function within another ?

Yes.  Code has other issues.

Comment: I never had to manually allocate as I previously only used java or python. Why is that needed ? Why isn't the declaration and initilisation enough for the compiler to know that it needs to allocate space for this variable ? The output contains the amplitudes of a modulated wave so if I decrease the number of samples I loose precision so I would like to avoid this if it is possible.

Comment: @le_lemon " Why is that needed ?" sounds like why C and other languages are different? Too broad. Suffice it that C assumes the coder is making reasonable sized code.    Code has various other precision issues outside of `sample_rate` consideration.  So only focusing on that hides the others.

Comment: "return output" Yes, I can see that warning maybe I should fix that one first, but because the error occurs before the return I didn't worry about it until now.

Comment: @le_lemon "the error occurs before the return ..." --> Good practice to solve all warnings before executing - saves time.

Comment: Ok I fixed it the way you suggested (see edit 2). I can't see any other warnings.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica malloc is the worst possible solution. Never ever use malloc when working with very limited resources uCs. Most industrial standards forbid dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @P__J__ How would you try to pass values to the dac at a constant speed of at least 1 value every 10us ? My thought was calculating the values befor passing anything. But im gonna try two things on monday: 1. check how long the calculation of one value takes (if that is too long) 2. check out the triangle wave generation feature of the hardware (might be a good alternative if I can just tell it to create a triangle wave with specific amplitude for a specific amount of time)

Answer (score 1):

1 value every 10uS makes only 100kSPS whis is not too much for this macro. In my designs I generate > 5MSPS signals without any problems. Usually I have one buffer and DMA in circular mode. First I fill the buffer and start generation. When the half transmition DMA interrupt is trigerred I fill the first half of the buffer with fresh data. The the transmition complete interrupt is trigerred I fill the second half and this process repeats all over again.

Comment: Thanks I am allready doing this at the ADC side so im gonna try this on monday.